# Does lua garbage collect upon an error?

Tags: c++, lua

I have a C++ program which uses lua. C++ exposes a reference counted datatype as userdata with an assigned finalizer so that lua can take ownership of such values.

This works fine. However one thing worries me: if there was to occur an error executing a script where lua holds instances of that datatype, will the finalizer be called then?

Another formulation of the question would be: Does lua run a garbage collection cycle upon an error?

Comment: Note that if you use Lua with C++, you should either compile Lua itself as C++ code, or be really careful about objects lifetime. In plain C Lua does `longjump()` on any error (including errors in C API), with all the expected consequences.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, everything continues to run fine if the error occurs inside a protected call. If Lua panics, then the Lua state is not in a usable condition.